# Magento 2.3.3 - Blank White Screen on Frontend (All Pages)

Tags: magento2, static-content, white-screen

I am getting a white screen returned for all front end pages on Magento 2.3.3. I am using a third party theme (Sahara Fashion 3), which I have extended from. The theme itself was loaded properly before this white screen started occurring after I added one less file (`style.less`) in `web/css/`.

In `system.log`, I got the following:

```
[2020-03-17 15:31:51] main.CRITICAL: Warning: file_put_contents(pub/static/frontend/extended_theme/base/en_US/css/style.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in vendor/wikimedia/less.php/lessc.inc.php on line 177 [] []
[2020-03-17 16:00:44] main.CRITICAL: Warning: file_put_contents(pub/static/frontend/extended_theme/base/en_US/css/style.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in vendor/wikimedia/less.php/lessc.inc.php on line 177 [] []
```

I got around that by removing a function call from the phtml file that seemed to be redundant. In case not, this is what I commented: `$block->renderFileLessToCss();`.

Still receiving a white screen with no errors. I can see the HTML being rendered in the element inspector yet I have a blank page.

I have reset permissions, resolved all error and critical items in system.log, flushed the caches, removed the static content manually, force deployed static content, switched to production and back to developer, but no changes at all. Still just a white screen.

What did I miss?

Comment: do you check permission for the style.less file?

Comment: Yes. I reset all permissions.

Comment: looks like it is not generating the style.css from less file and file not found in pub folder can you check if you have style.css in pub/static/frontend/extended_theme/base/en_US/css directory and add code for  renderFileLessToCss()

Comment: I can do that but I'm not getting new log entries that show errors and I removed style.less since I don't even actually need it. Still getting the same behavior. The function in question is one by PlazaThemes.

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', -1); add in bootstrap.php and check if it show error on frontend

Comment: There are no errors on the front end, nor in the logs. Just a white screen with the HTML rendered in the element viewer.

Comment: do you have it running on some domain? i can debug if you can give me access

Comment: It's at m2.uncommonthreadsyarn.com. If you can figure anything out, that would be great.

Comment: i found the reason and post my answer please accept if it helps Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visit your request domain http://m2.uncommonthreadsyarn.com/ it seems you are currently developing this I found the issue.
[image]

```
    @media (min-width: 768px), print html, body {
height: 100%;
display: none;
```

}

that display none is not showing you body at frontend after changing comment out display:none in browsers i see your content

[image]

Comment: I have no idea where that came from, but I'll find it and fix it. Can't believe I missed that!

Comment: yeah some time small issue can cause big trouble please accept this as answer if it helps

Comment: its coming from styles-l.css line 2015

Comment: Not sure which source file is causing it however.

Comment: styles-l.css search that file coming from frontend->frontend/UncommonThreads/base directory you can override these styles

Comment: I figured out the full root cause. Theme was not structured properly so LESS files would not compile correctly. Unnecessary function is no longer even needed. Thanks for the help.